# Why do I receive 402 code for request when implementing Digital Goods Purchase for Actions on Google?

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google, google-assistant-sdk

My Assistant app gets a status of `PEMISSION_DENIED` with a message saying that

> the caller does not have permission

I have followed all instructions here by this person: [Digital Goods Implementation](https://medium.com/@yoichiro/digital-goods-transaction-of-actions-on-google-build-android-app-59fdb221cfb)

I have created `APK`, managed `SKU` (valid status) items, Android app that became published (valid status), enabled `Actions API` from `Google API Console` and made a `service account key` for my project, and released my Assistant app for `beta` to test it. The `Connect App` status is `connected` and the toggle is on. I think everything required is completed but the error message does not get fixed, which means I cannot receive purchasable items I prepared in my `Google Developer Console`.

```
const createJwtClient = () => {
    const scopes = [
        "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/actions.purchases.digital"
    ];   
    return new google.auth.JWT(
        serviceAccount.client_email,
        null,
        serviceAccount.private_key,
        scopes,
        null
    );
};

const packageName = 'com.myproject.name'

const getSkus = (tokens, conv) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const url = `https://actions.googleapis.com/v3/packages/${packageName}/skus:batchGet`;
        const convId = conv.request.conversation.conversationId;
        const param = {
            conversationId: convId,
            skuType: "SKU_TYPE_IN_APP",
            ids: [
                "item-id1",
                "item-id2"
            ]
        };
        request.post(url, {
            auth: {
                bearer: tokens.access_token
            },
            json: true,
            body: param
        }, (err, httpResponse, body) => {
            if (err) {
                reject(err);
            } else {
                const statusCode = httpResponse.statusCode;
                const statusMessage = httpResponse.statusMessage;
                console.log(`${statusCode}: ${statusMessage}`);
                console.log(JSON.stringify(body));
                resolve(body);
            }
        });
    });
};
```

I expect I get purchasable items as JSON, but my request to fetch `SKU` seems to fail.

But I do receive `access_token` from `JWT` request using my `service account key`.

Could you point out something that is wrong??

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure your testing email is different from the Play Console Admin's email. Second, ensure you've added managed products and subscriptions to the Google Play Console (see below)[image] [image] The Actions on Google [Github sample](https://github.com/actions-on-google/dialogflow-digital-goods-nodejs) has been recently updated as well and the [Kotlin APK](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-play-billing/tree/master/TrivialDriveKotlin) has all the specifics in the 'Getting Started' section of the readme.

Comment: Thank you for the asnwer, but is adding subscription required?? I do not need the subscription for my app. Thanks.

Comment: Are you using the sample app provided in the digital goods sample? Because the Actions on Google digital goods sample does require both subscriptions and managed products. I'd suggest getting starting with the provided sample first. Have you enabled the Actions API through Google Cloud Platform and selected yes for digital goods use in the `Directory Information` section of the Actions console?